# How to get html page content on button click in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.ios

I am creating an application in that it gets data from the web view that opens from the page and when the user enters data and then save into that then it saves data into the database using c#.

I have to try to make a local Html webpage and on click of button try to get the value of Html page content but when I try with that I am not able to do that.

I also try with the hosted web URL but can't do that.

I am using .Net standard 2.0.3

Can anyone look into this and suggest to me what should I to do to achieve that?

Comment: Use EvaluvateJavascript like this link https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-webview-executing-javascript/  and pass it the string "document.documentElement.outerHTML;". That will get you the full HTML.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Is it gives me whole HTML page editor with `bold, italic` and other related operations on the editor? 
Is it only gives a simple text box and the user can enter text in the text field?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I also need same. I think https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor can help but it is older. Need RichEditor for .NetStandard. Do you have any such reference?